# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate doesn't return an error if Id is not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing an API that updates mongo DB data.
When I pass an ID which is not available then it's not throwing an error at `findByIdAndUpdate`. Instead it returns a blank result.

```
const update_data = async(data) => {

    try {

        const res = customReportModel.findByIdAndUpdate(data.input._id, data.input.body, {new: true}, function(err, model) {
            if(err) {
                console.error(error);
                const e = new Error(`Data with ${data.input._id} not found.`);
                throw e;
            }
            return model;
        })


    } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);
        const e = new Error('Error while updating.');
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Not sure why it's not throwing an error when the ID does not exist in the database.

Comment: [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) returns a document or `null` - `null` in case the to be updated document is not found (it is not an error).

Comment: Then what should I use to fulfill my requirement ?

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: If there's no id then it should return `error` no id found

Comment: You can check for null and do what your application is supposed to do. Like, a message to the user, perhaps, saying the document cannot be updated as it doesn't exist.

Comment: It won't throw error. Since it is not like you are passing an invalid ObjectId. If an ObjectId is not found, it will return null. So, if return is null that means record with ObjectId doesn't exist in collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const update_data = async(data) => {

    try {

        const res = customReportModel.findByIdAndUpdate(data.input._id, data.input.body, {new: true}, function(err, model) {
            if(!model) {
                const e = new Error(`Data with ${data.input._id} not found.`);
                throw e;
            } else{
                return model;
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        const e = new Error('Error while updating.');
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add
`if(!model) return res.status(404).send('[404]: Model with given id does not exist')`
before `return model`. Worked for me