# Error: Request failed with status code 404 axios.put

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I am trying to update my database with axios.

Here is my frontend part

```
const [updateData, setUpdateData] = useState({ price: "", sale: null });
 const updateProperty = async () => {
try {
  const response = await apiReq.put(
    `/propertys/update/${data._id}`,
    updateData
  );
  navigate(-1);
  console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

`onClick={updatePropert}` is executing this request.

Backend Controller :

```
export const updateProperty = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const property = await propertys.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!property) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Property doesn't exist." });
    }
    try {
      const updatedProperty = await propertys.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: req.body },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.status(200).json(updatedProperty);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692333/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-doesnt-return-an-error-if-id-is-not-found

Comment: @ArtemFedotov Not really :)

Comment: I see 2 possible reasons/error, First 404 is being thrown because your route is incorrect. Second you are entering `if` block and 404 is being thrown there. Can you verify which scenario is happening? Do you get message `Property doesn't exist.`?

Comment: @bajrax could share your 404 response body?